# Append elements of List1 that are different from List2 Different elements from in prolog

Tags: prolog

I am currently trying to find all elements of Lists L1 and L2 that are different from each other and append them into List L.

So far, I tried the following:

```
 difference(L1, L2, L) :-
     findall(H, (member(H,L1),\+member(H, L2)), L).
```

However, I only get an empty list when I query the following:

```
 |?- difference([1,2,3],[1,2,3,4,5,6], L).
```

I also tried querying the following:

```
 |?- difference([1,2,3,4,5,6],[1,2,3], L).
```

Interestingly, for this one I get L = [4,5,6]. How can I rewrite my fact to for it to work also with the first query?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prolog lists difference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9687121/prolog-lists-difference)

Comment: This is indeed a duplicate, however I am curious why my solution was not working :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your definition reads "all elements of L1 that are not in L2".
What you want is "all elements of L1 **or** L2 that are not in L1 **and** L2"

```
difference(L1, L2, L) :-
     findall(H, ((member(H,L1);member(H,L2)),\+(member(H,L1),member(H,L2))), L).
```

Comment: Ah, I see, such a simple mistake! Thank you so much!